# Content Encoding Error when loading an URL in browser

Tags: apache-2.2, compression

One particular page on our site - http://www.newint.org/issues/1979/10/01/ - gives a Content Encoding Error when loaded in a browser. In Firefox, it says:

"Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

Safari gives a similar warning, saying  “cannot decode raw data”. I've Googled this but found nothing relevant. All our pages are served compressed, but this page is no different from the many others that work. When I fetch it with `wget -s http://www.newint.org/issues/1979/10/01/`
 it seems to work fine, and the first lines of the resultant file are the same as those of other files that work in my browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Mon, 11 Jul 2011 10:47:15 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 34445
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2011 09:47:16 GMT
X-Varnish: 396024918
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Does anyone have any solutions or things I could test?

Comment: Downloading program (ReGet) downloads this file fine .. but Firefox & Chrome -- they receiving different response: `Vary: Accept-Encoding`, `Content-Encoding: gzip`, `Content-Length: 9311`, `Age: 335`. Maybe check Varnish config?

Comment: @LazyOne Is there anything specific in our Varnish config to check? I can paste a particular config file here if that helps...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Varnish at all -- cannot help here, sorry.

Comment: I meet exactly the same problem, just one page on my site can't render. Can you please elaborate what virtural include has problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem - an Apache virtual include referred to a directory rather than a file. Hopefully it'll help someone else to know this can give the above error.